# Which stackexchange should I use?

Tags: discussion

This stackexchange is "meant" for people working in academia or PhD students. One can feel that undergraduates are only "somewhat tolerated". I have written several questions that I ended up not posting (some of them do violate the guidelines, I understand that this site has its purposes and I respect that). I still do not know the answers to these questions.

I'm currently on my last year of undergraduate studies, in Europe, but as an international, and thus I have a lot of questions. There are many weird factors at play, so my **question** is: Is there a stackexchange suited for people in my position (that is, confused soon to graduate **kids**)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Probably not on StackExchange.** Note that SE makes no claim to "span the space"; there are many questions that do not fit on any SE in the network. These include both questions that "could" belong on a SE (for example, we currently have no SE about the Persian language, though other languages do have an SE and a Persian one might be created in the future), and questions that are not a good fit for our format at all (e.g., "What is the best kind of apple?" will never be on-topic, regardless how many SEs we open).

Off site, I sometimes see people get directed to reddit, though I personally have no idea which of the subreddits are complementary to us.

Regarding undergrads: these days, our stance is that we don't take questions about undergrad admissions, life, or culture. Everything else is OK, including questions about coursework, advising, ethics, graduate admissions, etc.

But I suspect the real problem might not be that your questions are off-topic, but that you are not phrasing them in a way that is likely to generate answers. Looking at [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178424/asking-for-a-recommendation-letter-when-i-am-only-close-with-professors-that-ha) one as an example, let me give some hints:

- This seems like a duplicate; we have many, many questions in our archives about how to handle letters of recommendation when you don't have many strong relationships with professors. [This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107823/recommendation-letter-from-professor-who-doesnt-know-me-very-well) one, for example. If you've already read these questions but your issue is not resolved, you should make sure the difference between your question and the existing ones is clear.
- The title doesn't have a question mark, and when the question finally appears (in the third paragraph), you ask "is the assertion above true?". Being crystal clear and very direct about what you're asking is very important (both here and in real life).
- We also recommend posting one question per post. Adding another question in the last paragraph tends to make things incoherent.
- Counter-intuitively, shorter tends to be better. I would challenge you to rewrite the question using half as many words. People can always ask for more details in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

Most questions about academia that are not allowed on this site are best answered by an academic at your university.  Ask one of them, or ask them who to ask.

Comment: If I could ask an academic at my university I would have done it instead of resorting to "anonymous strangers online". I am an international student, there are barriers. I think that some of the academics are wary about mis-steps when dealing with international students. I can definitely tell that some prefer no interaction, rather than risking bad interactions.

Comment: Since the people answering questions on this site are from a variety of questions, it's still an "international" interaction.  This might be the best help you can get: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor